# Is it possible for objects not to be affected during render process

Tags: modeling, rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have a scene with 3 cubes, Blue, White, Red. In the middle the white is covering up a section of the red cube. When I toggle on off the white cube, the shadow gets affected on the red cube side. I need to export from Blender each individual object the way it appears in the render, but when I turn off the objects, the shadow and lights also disappear from the rendered image. So is there a way to hide objects without losing the the way its influencing other objects in the scene?

[image]

Comment: Hello are you in Eevee or Cycles?

Comment: EEVEE render, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can get away with this: create a material using *Transparent BSDF* <s>set its color's alpha to zero</s> leave the RGB values full white (thx @GordonBrinkmann) and enable alpha blending under *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode*. Leave the *Shadow Mode* as *Opaque*. This gives a completely invisible object which still throws shadows.

[image]

Comment: It is not necessary to set the color's alpha to zero. In fact, the _Alpha_ value of an RGB color has no effect in the _Shader Editor_ and many other parts of Blender at all. It can only be used in the _Compositor_. Especially in the _Transparent BSDF_, the RGB values are what creates the transparency - a value of 1 means full transparency, a value of 0 full opacity, so it is the opposite of the alpha values, which is basically an opacity value.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oh wow, i didn't know. Thanks for sharing, i edit my answer.

Comment: I was editing my comment but somehow the changes got sent before I finished and now time is up to correct my slightly misunderstandable addition. What I wanted to say is, the _Transparent BSDF_ creates RGB coded colored transparency, where each channel can have a different percentage of transparency. But the alpha channel is a greyscale value of opacity percentage. Alpha can only say, how opaque a material is in all colors whereas the _Transparent BSDF_ can tint the transparency.

Comment: By the way, the part which is relevant in _Eevee_ for the shadow to be visible although the object is invisible is the _Shadow Mode_ setting directly below the _Blend Mode_. If you keep the shadow to be _Opaque_, it will be visible on a transparent object.

Comment: Got it. The takeaway for this case is still that changing the alpha value doesn't do anything for the render outcome, right? And yes, the shadow setting must be opaque of course. I didn't mentioned it because it's set as default when creating a new material but this may be overlooked.

Comment: Hello Forum. Thank you for the replies, but this wouldn't work for my current set up. I have multiple objects with various textures and materials, in different collections. So it would be a tedious task to apply alpha to each individual object. So is it possible to apply the Alpha to the collection itself with the objects inside it? That would work for what I'm after.

https://ibb.co/GFgc9nh

Comment: @blenderbreath tbh this sounds like a new question as i believe you need scripting then.

Comment: Ill post a new question. thank you.

Comment: Just to draw this to a conclusion since this thread is already too long: Yes, the color's alpha does not do anything for the render. Not even for mixing, see the following examples, I've used a separate RGB node here: a reddish color, alpha is 0.5 (note that the output is called _Color_) but the object is opaque: [red cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKrOg.jpg). A black/white factor mix between blue with alpha 1.0 and orange at alpha 0.5 shows the full orange: [blue/orange cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIXie.jpg). Even in the _Compositor_, the alpha channel is not used for the _Mix_ node.

Comment: (run out of space) Only when you are using the _Alpha Over_ node in the _Compositor_, the alpha channel of an _RGB_ node is taken into account (note that the output in this case is called _RGBA_): [blue color with apha 0.5 over rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZI3O.jpg). In the _Compositor_ the _Separate Color_ node also has 4 outputs, _Red_, _Green_, _Blue_ and _Alpha_ while in the _Shader Editor_ there are only 3 for the color channels, the alpha is missing.

Comment: Great additions, much appreciated!